# Black Screen ubuntu 12.04

Tags: grub2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

Hey guys,
I was using my Ubuntu 12.04 and today I had a problem:

I was running virtual box, photoshop and doing some updates, when ubuntu "explorer" went missing. The top and bottom bars disappeared too.

The only thing that remained was the "explorer" window, I couldn't press ALT+TAB to change programs, seemed like the "explorer" was frozen.

I tryied rebooting the system manually, but when I turned it on again, after the classic purple screen with the dots, the screen went back, neither my keyboard nor my mouse work.

Already tryed ubuntu 12 LiveCD, boot-repair and recommended repais, but the problem persists.

So, anyone can give me a hint of what happened or how can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Pode ser que falhou alguma coisa no update, tenta entrar no [Recovery Mode](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RecoveryMode).

Se não funcionar, tenta apertar F8 antes depois do *grub* iniciar, vai aparecer uma tela de comandos, tenta os comandos mais comuns:

- `sudo apt-get update`
- `sudo apt-get upgrade`

Para tentar reinstalar a parte gráfica:

- `sudo apt-get install gnome-panel`

ou se você usar o unity:

- `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop`